# "Cannot enumerate sites" while listing Sites with filter clause

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am stuck with a peculiar request and I'm not sure what/if I did something wrong.

I tries to call something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$filter=name eq 'Adele Vance'
```

where Adele Vance is a correct site name.
I end up with this error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Cannot enumerate sites",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-07-27T16:37:12",
        "request-id": "bebcc514-7e4e-4ffe-9987-4f1c9fd24f8e",
        "client-request-id": "bebcc514-7e4e-4ffe-9987-4f1c9fd24f8e"
    }
}
```

}

And I'm not quite sure why.

Has someone an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

`$filter` clause is available only for [Beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) not v1.0.

You can use `$search` clause.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search="Adele Vance"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
`$filter` is not working on beta either, but it's a beta I dod not expect anything.
More important, the `$search` clause does not seems to return personal sites, especially in my case `$filter="Adele Vance"` is not returning anything. I will investigate further